# How to maintain checkbox selected after navigation through different pages in jsgrid through jquery?

Tags: jquery, jsgrid

Unable to maintain the data or (checkbox selection) after page navigation? or we can say for example:i am on page 1 of JSGRID and i have checked 2 rows using a check box available on that row and I navigate to second page and again come back to first one than the selection lost.

Comment: Either save it in your model/viewbag, or use $POST/$SESSION. Google is your friend here.

Answer (score 1):

Add a field on the data item to track the checkbox state. In `itemTemplate` restore the value on each rendering.

```
{ 
    name: "FieldName", 
    align: "center",
    itemTemplate: function(value, item) {
        return $("<input>").attr("type", "checkbox")
                .attr("checked", value || item.Checked)
                .on("change", function() {
                    item.Checked = $(this).is(":checked");
                });
    }
}
```

Here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/xo1npabw/

As alternative you can store checkbox state in a separate array like in the demo "Batch Delete" on the [demo page](http://js-grid.com/demos/).